# NodeJS libstdc error on CentOS 6.10 (EasyApache,cPanel)

Tags: centos6, node.js

I have installed NodeJS 8.9.3 and that was running perfectly. but after that i have started a project and that needs NodeJS Version > 10.0 so i updated my NodeJS 8.9.3 to currently stable version via NVM.
but after updating i got error.

Error Log >

```
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

I don't know what to do. i am trying to solve this issue from past 48 hours and i have researched a lot but not found any solution.

This would be great help for me.

Comment: I have no way of checking this right now, but it seems that CentOS 6 simply has too old glibc versions. It will be EOLed by the end of the year anyways - take this as an additional push to upgrade.

Comment: i will try to update. Thank you @JanDorniak for your response.